Manhwa or manhua in which the main character can steal/take the skills of defeated enemies
I read this manhwa or manhua where the white-haired main character (MC) was looked down upon. His class had a challenge to defeat beasts, so he comes across this kid that doesn't like him and kills him. The kid he killed had a wind blade talent and was part of a strong family, so the father sent someone out to kill him. When he found and attacked the MC, the killer noticed the wind blade technique and knew that he killed the Head Family's son, but the MC still killed him.

The main character seems very unlikeable and violent. Was that the impression you were trying to give?

Im literally just trying to find out what it was called bc I forgot.

But was he actually a likeable and nice person, or was he some sort of anti-hero or villain that we're following around?
